# Why Angular Material is not being installed in my latest Angular Application which is version 13?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Recently I created a new angular application with latest version of Angular: 13.1.1 and I am trying to install angular Material but I'm unable to see the material folder in node modules.

Below is the screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DktZW.png)

I included all the modules into material.module.ts file imported that in app.module.ts file and I'm trying to use the material modules in the my homepage component and I'm getting these errors
[Material Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sURLG.png)

[angular material installed cli image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRgjS.png)

Material.module.ts file
[Material.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbyeL.png)

App.module.ts file
[app.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqDrP.png)

Comment: Did you get any error in console? How r u adding angular material?

Comment: By using this command ng add @angular/material and I'm not getting any error in console, I can't see the @material folder in node modules no matter how many times I tried to install it and restarted VSC and computer also.

Comment: check inside your @angular folder

Comment: If i rememeber correctly material will be added to @angular/material folder. Plz check in that folder it should be there.

Comment: Yeah I found the folder but I am adding all modules into material.module.ts and added that in app.module.ts file and I'm getting these errors        Error: src/app/navbar/logout-dialog.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'mat-dialog-title' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-dialog-title' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-dialog-title' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: Show the sample code of material.module.ts and app.module.ts in updated question.

Comment: I add the sample codes in the question, can you please look at them

Comment: You already have an array in variable Material, so remove "[ & ]" in import and exports section, For ex- exports: Material & imports: Material

Comment: But the same code worked for Angular 11 and I'm trying to update my application to 13 version, and this code is not working for angular 13

Comment: Hi @VennelaJajiri, welcome to SO, please add your code into code snippets, this is important to help you much better, check this [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9676887)

Answer (score 0):

It should be in @angular/material

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).